# Entry Unique to User

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that keeps track of websites, and want it to be unique to that user. For example if the site is google.com, the user can only enter it once, however still allow multiple users can enter google.com. To give you a better idea here is my models.py:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    user = models.ForeignKey('customauth.UserProfile')
```

Is there anyway to make the url field unique to users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `unique_together constraint`,

```
class Site(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    user = models.ForeignKey('customauth.UserProfile')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('url', 'user')
```

This option allows a user to create a unique url, else django raises an error. A single user cannot create two objects with same url.

The ValidationError raised during model validation when the constraint is violated has the unique_together error code.

Comment: When I save a second site with the same url in admin, it still creates a new entry, except the name (which I have set to `return self.url`) shows up as blank. Can it be, because one of the fields is a foreign key?

Comment: I tried, the same in my machine. Site with a url created, then with same user and another tag, but the same url tried. but admin, raises error for me